# how to free unused memory in android?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc

i had downloaded an app but after connecting my phone(HTC ChaCha) to pc and after disconnecting my phone from pc,i found that the app is not working any longer.Rather the phone was failing to recognise the app.So i uninstalled it.But after uninstallation the memory occupied by the app was not freed.how can i free that memory?

Comment: Are you talking about RAM, or storage?

Answer (score 0):

In settings, see if you can find something called "Application manager". When in that, find the "all" list. See if the deleted app is still listed there. If yes, there should be a few options to clear the data it stores, use them. I am not sure how your android looks like, but they should generally be the same.

If that does not help, you can use this app: Clean master - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=eng

I use it on my private phone, and it seems to do good when it comes to free up memory. However, I am unsure if it work on your phone, as it does not list all versions it supports. It's also free.

You can also connect the phone to your computer again and see if you can remove the app data manually, however, how this can be done differ between phone models, and it can be risky as the data you want to delete might not be found so easily.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion.had tried this kinda apps before but were of no use.this one is good.did work.couldnt free the whole memory but it was helpful somewhat!

Comment: If the app had some effect, I will dare say that my last suggestion, involving connecting the phone to the PC again, will be the final and probably best step to remove it all. Sadly tho, as also stated, I can't help much there, as it will involve a lot more than simply knowing the phone model and android version

Comment: actually my phone's internal memory is really low.there lies the problem.and i will surely try whatever you suggested and if it works i will let you know.

Comment: I did a quick search on your phone, and I found out it only has 512 MB of internal memory. I will be honest and say that is quite, quite low. In that case cleaning some "wasted" memory will only get you so far, I found out it supports SD (memory) cards. I suggest you simply go and get one of those to buff your memory. Unless you use the phone to take a lot of pictures, or store a lot of music, a 1 or 2 GB card will do fine, and likely not cost a lot either.

Comment: Thanks for doing a research on my phone.i do use a 8gb memory card but no matter what the applications take up a lot of space in my phone's internal memory so whatever i do this memory thing bugs me a lot.i did try what you said but it was of very little help actually.Thanks anyway for your suggestions.